# Conservation of momentum homework problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, conservation-laws

A 2-stage rocket travels $1200 \text{ m/s}$ relative to earth.  When the first stage runs out of fuel, the explosive bolt separates the first stage from the second with a velocity of $35 \text{ m/s}$ relative to the second stage. If the first stage is 3 times as massive as the second stage, what is the velocity of the second stage after?

So I did the question with conservation of momentum, with the second stage as the frame of reference:

$4m(0)=(-35)3m+mv$, the $m$ cancels out and you get $v=105\text{ m/s}$.

You add that to the $1200 \text{ m/s}$ initial velocity and you get $1305 \text{ m/s}$ as the final velocity.

But the answer in the textbook says the answer is $12 \text{ km/s}$. where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation is wrong, the relative speed of first stage to second stage in your equation is v+35, not 35.